# Crunchy icon rescaling on non-standard dpi display

Tags: windows-8.1, high-dpi

I've got a laptop with FullHD resolution on a 15" screen so I've set the display DPI to 125%

Now system fonts are looking better but some of the icons, those that doesn't have the exact resolution needed, look really "crunchy". Their size is right, it's just that they are not re-scaled properly.

The screenshot below shows three icons, two of them re-scaled and comparison between the same icon on standard-dpi display and 125% dpi display.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to change it so that the icons are rescaled with interpolation?